# Why JMeter HTTP Proxy server is not recording my local WebApp

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, weblogic, performance-testing

I am working with Jmeter 3.1 version and trying to record my local web page. I use a recording template with the default configuration:

```
File-->Templates-->Recording-->Create
```

After this, i changued the browser (iexplore) LAN settings:

```
Internet options --> Connections --> LAN settings
```

[image]

finally, i started the Test Script Recorder using the default configuration created by the template:

[image]

[image]

The issue is Jmeter is not recording anything for my
localhost page [HTTP]:

http://localhost:7001/MyPage

recording result:

[image]

but it does for my  server deployed app [HTTPS]:

https://168.12.4.20/System/MyPage

Recording result:

[image]

When I follow the instructions in the official manual, the same thing happens

What am I doing wrong? Any recommendation ?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try disabling automatic proxy configuration

[image: IE Auto Proxy Config]

JMeter should not "feel" the difference between local and remote deployments, it captures HTTP Requests which are being made by the web browser through its proxy. If JMeter isn't able to "see" the request it normally indicates one of the following:

1. The request doesn't go into the proxy
2. JMeter isn't able to "understand" the request (it is not HTTP/HTTPS protocol, JMeter's certificate is not installed in browser, etc.)

You can try out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) as an alternative way of recording a JMeter script, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but i had to use firefox  to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make work JMETER with IEXPLORE. I had to use a old version of firefox (for applets support). I installed the 50.1.0 firefox versión and works 
with the next configuration (using default template for recording):

[image: Working configuration]

The problem appeared to be my IEXPLORE browser. Not work even after i install the microsoft loopback adapter. I read that this adapter might be the problem.

My Solution:

- Remove current version of firefox (using revo uninstaller). this is because the new version can't allow java plugin (My Webapp uses it).
- Install old firefox version with advanced settings (disable auto update)
- Create default template for recording and  start
- Set de above configuration [Working configuration]
- Test my WebApp a recording the request

Thanks!